# ConfuserEx - fail to resolve dependency only on publish

Tags: c#, confuserex

Using ConfuserEx - when I build the file normally I have no problems, but when I am in publish mode I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to resolve dependency of 'TheProgram.exe'. 1>
>   Exception: dnlib.DotNet.AssemblyResolveException: Could not resolve
>   assembly: mwqJVcPLiNUjsUEcAQtUUhNeTADJ, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null 1>     at
>   dnlib.DotNet.Extensions.ResolveThrow(IAssemblyResolver self, IAssembly
>   assembly, ModuleDef sourceModule) in
>   E:\Source\Public\Confuser2\dnlib\src\DotNet\IAssemblyResolver.cs:line
>   113 1>     at Confuser.Core.ConfuserEngine.Inspection(ConfuserContext
>   context) in
>   e:\Source\Public\Confuser2\Confuser.Core\ConfuserEngine.cs:line 264

Usually with these sorts of errors, you have to include the assembly in the `<probePath>` in the project build file, but this seems like it is an internal dependency to something already obfuscated, as the assembly name is already obfuscated.

Any light anyone could shine on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: strange error, filename is meaningless... Sometimes I need to add some references as external, with the external flag: '<module path="yourExternalDLL.dll" external="true" />'